# get current page not full url

Tags: php, url

Is it possible to save the current page in a variable (not the full url) using php

So if my page is `www.mywebsite.com/news/bob`

I am looking to get `/bob` in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?PHP $file_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
```

maybe you need

```
basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] doesn't seem to exist on my install. Not sure what the story is there, but if it's not on mine, it may not be on yours so here's some alternatives.

```
$current_page = '/' . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$current_page = '/' . basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$current_page = '/' . basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

I find $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to be quite dependable.

If you're fond of regular expressions you could try

```
$current_page = preg_replace('/(.*?\/)+(.*)$/', '/$2', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] on included or required files, then it will return the current file, not the URL of the current page. On Windows machines, the only reliable options are $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL'] however, these will include any querystring as well.

You would need to strip the query string off the end of the URL to get the part you want.

```
$current_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_page = substr($current_page, 0, strpos($current_page, "?")); //removes query string
$current_page =  = '/' . array_pop(array_filter(explode("/", $current_page)));
```